# How can I map different routes to the same ApiController?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have a UsersController in my ASP.NET Web Api 2.2 project and I would like to expose it directly as well as nested.

For example:

/api/users

and

/api/accounts/{id:guid}/users

The first route would be used to deal with all users and the second would be used to limit the scope to the users associated with that particular account id.

I've been using [RoutePrefix("api/users")] for my routing, but it won't let me apply multiple RoutePrefix attributes.  How do I accomplish this without being able to use multiple RoutePrefix attributes on the same controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not having two controllers classes: UserController and AccountController? Each one with its own RoutPrefix attribute. The first one with RoutePrefix[("api/users")] and the second one with RoutePrefix("api/accounts").

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing.  I decided it was not only easier on me, but less confusing to api consumers to make only one Users endpoint.